# Multi monitor solutions. Will these two video cards work on Linux?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm a bit tired of searching for the optimal solution to multi monitor setup in Linux.

- I don't want to spend money on a Matrox TripleHead2Go.
- Multi monitor on SLI for Linux doesn't work, check [this thread](http://crap.linuxfusion.net/?p=288) and [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=149688).

The question is, if I buy [two video cards](http://newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130609) **without SLI support**, will they work?

My plan is to connect 3 monitors, this card has two DVI ports for each one.

**UPDATE: I bought them (see my answer below)**

Comment: I don't use Linux but there's no need in Windows for SLI support (in fact, SLI can PREVENT you from using some of your extra video outputs!)

Comment: For those that are voting off-topic: Watch twice, this is not a product recommendation but a request for advice that is necessary to decide what he can buy. Read [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) before closing...

Answer (score 1):

If that does not work an alternative is to use a Pluggable USB video adapter, it seems to work under [Linux](http://plugable.com/2010/08/18/displaylink-linux-kernel-driver-udlfb-updates-slated-for-2-6-37/) with kernel 2.6.31, and it is relatively cheap (less than $50).

I use [this one](http://plugable.com/products/USB-VGA-165/)

Answer (score 1):

That video card should work fine, but you will probably need to install [NVidia's properitary Linux drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) for the best performance.  (Many distributions, including Ubuntu, make it easy to install third-party drivers in their graphical interface and will prompt you if they detect you can make use of these drivers.)

Answer (score 1):

I bought them, and using Ubuntu 11.04 configured them with xorg, with a little help of the "nvidia-setup" command.

Everything runs fine, the tree monitors, even two of them rotated. The only problem is that [xinerama breaks RandR](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/157319) but that's a bug in Nvidia's drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 monitors is not easy at all. In this case I would suggest you to buy an ATI graphics card with three or more ports. I personally don't use ATI's, but my colleagues told me that the multi monitor support of ATI os much more advanced and usable than the nvidia's.

Comment: I think that's true (ATI support vs Nvidia support), read my answer on why. And, about having a card with 3 ports, it may not support the three monitors at the same time.